# SetInterval function is not creating delay in Javascript code

Tags: javascript

Hi Everyone I am having trouble using the setInterval function. I have it set to 10 seconds in each of the situations below, however the functions inside are executing as fast as they normally would. I am new to javascript could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (tempArray.length == 4) {

    var counter = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    //console.log("counting average...");

    for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
      sum += tempArray[i]; //add each temperature together 
      counter++;
    }
  }

  var average = (sum / counter).toFixed(2);
  setInterval(function() {
    var avgString = "Data reveived, the average temperature is " + average + "*C";


    console.log(avgString);
    io.emit('chat message', avgString);
  }, 10000);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: what do you mean as fast as they usually would? The Interval means execute every X amount of time. It's not used for creating a delay. Perhaps you want `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tempArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var counter = 0;
var sum = 0;
var average = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  //console.log("counting average...");

  tempArray = [
    Math.random() * 10,
    Math.random() * 10,
    Math.random() * 10,
    Math.random() * 10,
    Math.random() * 10
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
    sum += tempArray[i]; //add each temperature together
    counter++;
  }

  average = (sum / counter);
  setTimeout(function() {
    var avgString = "Data reveived, the average temperature is " + (sum / counter) + "*C";

    console.log(avgString);
  }, 1 * 1000);
}, 1 * 2000);
```